# Python function and classes error

Tags: python, function, class

I want to display the properties in the class `AkaliStats` below.

```
class AkaliStats:
    games_played=60
    kda=3.27
    winrate=59
    lane='top'
ObjA=AkaliStats()

def display(object,property):
    print 'property'
    getattr(ObjA,'property')

display(ObjA,'winrate')
```

Comment: What does *"won't work"* mean, exactly? What are you expecting the output to be, and what happens instead? Are you looking for `getattr(ObjA, 'winrate')`, perhaps?

Comment: yes im trying to get the winrate that is 59 from above but instead python says that winrate is not defined

Comment: So **include that information in the question**. And of course it's not defined, because there is no global name `winrate`. You need either `ObjA.winrate` or the snippet I've already posted. Also, you know those are *class* not *instance* attributes?

Comment: oh ok but can i make a function so that i can print name of the property which is winrate and the information to that which is 59???

Comment: Why did you think that would work? Why do you ignore the `property` parameter and use the string literal `'property'` instead?`AlkaliStats` instances don't have a `property` attribute, so that won't work. You need to pay closer attention to the differences between names and strings.

Comment: iv have deleted ''this but python states that winrate is not defined again.. really appreciate ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names and strings **are not the same**. You ignore both of the parameters inside the function - **why?!** Also, you neither `print` nor `return` the attribute. That should be:

```
def display(obj, property):
    print property
    print getattr(obj, property)

display(ObjA, 'winrate')
```

Play close attention here to what are *names* (e.g. `property`) and what are *strings* (e.g. `'winrate'`). Also, if you use the name `object` you will shadow the built-in, so I've used `obj` instead.

Comment: thnx man for ur advice it works now!! i will try to distinguish strings and names